# How much fertilizer is too much when feeding mangoes

Tags: seedlings, fertilizer, irrigation, tropical, mango

A Mango growing publication from University of Florida recommends a total of 1.5-3 lb of 8-3-9-2 fertilizer for example. (680-1360 g)

My growing season is about 6-7 months (~26 weeks) and my fertilizer strength is about twice of the mentioned one 14-6-20-4 so let's just assume that I would need about half of the amount which is 340-680g

I prefer to fertilize every time I water a seedling, which is around 10L each week.

When we do the math we get a dose of 13-26g in each watering which is 1.3-2.6g/L.

Should I be worried about that much fertilizer in the irrigation water? (I'm using the most expensive fertilizers with no chloride)

I have very calcareous sandy soil mostly poor in almost everything.

[image]
[image]